# perl command line multiline regex substitute

Tags: regex, perl, unix

I'm trying to substitute a multiline block using perl command line.
the text is the following:

```
@LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
TTTCCATTGCAGGTTTTAAAGTGGAGATTCTGAAGGGGAAAATAGGCACTGTCAGAACAAAGCTACCTGGAAACAG
+LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
DD@:BBBBDDD@D:B::=:6:(6//;589444004':839>>2;;:':>>:7B:><B<B#################
@LNCaP.2623 GAPC:1:1:4767:1343 length=76

+LNCaP.2623 GAPC:1:1:4767:1343 length=76

@LNCaP.2624 GAPC:1:1:4794:1349 length=76
```

and I tried to run the following regex:

```
perl -pe "s/^@.*\n\s*\n+//mg" test.txt
```

hoping to get the following output:

```
@LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
TTTCCATTGCAGGTTTTAAAGTGGAGATTCTGAAGGGGAAAATAGGCACTGTCAGAACAAAGCTACCTGGAAACAG
+LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
DD@:BBBBDDD@D:B::=:6:(6//;589444004':839>>2;;:':>>:7B:><B<B#################
@LNCaP.2624 GAPC:1:1:4794:1349 length=76
```

the regex `^@.*\n\s*\n\+.*\n\s*\n` recognize 4 lines I want to delete on regex101.com using the text above, however, when I run the command from my shell, the output is unchanged :(

I can't use the line number since this is an extract from a much much bigger file, which means that this has to be applied to all the 4 row instances that match that pattern.

any idea what am I doing wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`perl -pe` does line by line processing.  So using a regex that spans lines is never going to match by default.

You can change the [`input record separator $/`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) though, to slurp the entire file and apply the regex to it:

```
perl -pe "BEGIN { undef $/ } s/^@.*\n\s*\n+//mg" test.txt
```

The regex you suggested above doesn't provide the output you want though.  To do that, you'd need the following expression:

```
perl -pe "BEGIN {undef $/} s/^@.*\n\s*\n(?:(?!\@).*\n)*//mg" text.txt
```

Outputs:

```
@LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
TTTCCATTGCAGGTTTTAAAGTGGAGATTCTGAAGGGGAAAATAGGCACTGTCAGAACAAAGCTACCTGGAAACAG
+LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
DD@:BBBBDDD@D:B::=:6:(6//;589444004':839>>2;;:':>>:7B:><B<B#################
@LNCaP.2624 GAPC:1:1:4794:1349 length=76
```

Comment: also `perl -MData::Dumper -0777 -E'say Dumper $/'`

Answer (score 0):

[Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1733163/miller) is right in his answer. You have to read the whole content of the file to a variable and apply a regular expression to it. Try following code where I read the content in slurp mode and use a negative character class `[^\n]*` to match each line and `\n{2,}` to match blank lines:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = do { undef $/; <DATA> };
$text =~ s/^@(?:[^\n]*\n{2,}){2}//mg;
print $text;


__DATA__
@LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
TTTCCATTGCAGGTTTTAAAGTGGAGATTCTGAAGGGGAAAATAGGCACTGTCAGAACAAAGCTACCTGGAAACAG
+LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
DD@:BBBBDDD@D:B::=:6:(6//;589444004':839>>2;;:':>>:7B:><B<B#################
@LNCaP.2623 GAPC:1:1:4767:1343 length=76

+LNCaP.2623 GAPC:1:1:4767:1343 length=76

@LNCaP.2624 GAPC:1:1:4794:1349 length=76
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

That yields:

```
@LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
TTTCCATTGCAGGTTTTAAAGTGGAGATTCTGAAGGGGAAAATAGGCACTGTCAGAACAAAGCTACCTGGAAACAG
+LNCaP.2622 GAPC:1:1:4519:1350 length=76
DD@:BBBBDDD@D:B::=:6:(6//;589444004':839>>2;;:':>>:7B:><B<B#################
@LNCaP.2624 GAPC:1:1:4794:1349 length=76
```